# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "driver" is null

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running the below TestNG code

```
package pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import pages.createinvoicepom;


public class InvoiceCreationSanity {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void SetUp() throws InterruptedException {
        TestNG_Demo Setupobject = new TestNG_Demo();
        Setupobject.SetUp();
        Setupobject.signin();
            
        }
    
    @Test
    public void invoicecreation()  {
    
    createinvoicepom.createinvoice(driver).click();
        
        
    }
    
    public void result() {
        System.out.println("Test Completed Successfully");
    }
}
```

But getting the error as Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "driver" is null

In the @BeforeTest I'm calling the methods from another class and that is

```
package pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pages.dashloginpagepom;
import pages.createinvoicepom;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class TestNG_Demo {
    
    public static WebDriver driver;

    
    @BeforeTest
    public void SetUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
        
    
    @Test   
    public void signin() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("https://zolvitdash.vakilsearch.com/login");
        dashloginpagepom.Phone_number(driver).sendKeys("8825892445");
        dashloginpagepom.continue_button(driver).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        dashloginpagepom.otpone(driver).sendKeys("0");
        dashloginpagepom.otptwo(driver).sendKeys("0");
        dashloginpagepom.otpthree(driver).sendKeys("0");
        dashloginpagepom.otpfour(driver).sendKeys("0");
        dashloginpagepom.cont(driver).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        }
    
    @AfterTest
    public void result() {
        driver.close();
    System.out.println("Test Completed Successfully");
    }
}
```

Then in the @Test I'm calling the objects from another class and that is

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class createinvoicepom {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    
    public static WebElement element = null;
    
    public static WebElement createinvoice(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='styles_btnContent__7MVVu']"));
        return element;
        }
    
    public static WebElement additemfromdatabase(WebDriver driver) {
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Add items from database')]"));
        return element;
    }
    
    public static WebElement addbutton(WebDriver driver) {
        
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@class='mantine-ActionIcon-transparent mantine-ActionIcon-root event-track mantine-1dw43f4'])[2]"));
        return element;
    }
    
}
```

What mistake I'm doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you have defined 2 static `WebDriver` objects:

- `TestNG_Demo.driver`
- `InvoiceCreationSanity.driver`

You have just initialized `TestNG_Demo.driver` but `InvoiceCreationSanity` class is using `InvoiceCreationSanity.driver`, which is null.

You can choose to set your `InvoiceCreationSanity.driver` with `TestNG_Demo.driver` so that `invoicecreation()` can use the initialized `driver`:

```java
public class InvoiceCreationSanity {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void SetUp() throws InterruptedException {
        TestNG_Demo Setupobject = new TestNG_Demo();
        driver = Setupobject.SetUp(); // Set InvoiceCreationSanity.driver here
        Setupobject.signin();
            
    }
    
    @Test
    public void invoicecreation()  {
        // As driver is set above, now it is initialized and the function should run properly
        createinvoicepom.createinvoice(driver).click();
    }
    
    public void result() {
        System.out.println("Test Completed Successfully");
    }
}
```

```java
public class TestNG_Demo {
    
    public static WebDriver driver;

    
    // You have to return the WebDriver for this function
    @BeforeTest
    public WebDriver SetUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;
    }
        
    
    @Test   
    public void signin() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("https://zolvitdash.vakilsearch.com/login");
        dashloginpagepom.Phone_number(driver).sendKeys("8825892445");
        dashloginpagepom.continue_button(driver).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        dashloginpagepom.otpone(driver).sendKeys("0");
        dashloginpagepom.otptwo(driver).sendKeys("0");
        dashloginpagepom.otpthree(driver).sendKeys("0");
        dashloginpagepom.otpfour(driver).sendKeys("0");
        dashloginpagepom.cont(driver).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    }
    
    @AfterTest
    public void result() {
        driver.close();
        System.out.println("Test Completed Successfully");
    }
}
```

Side Note: It is a good practice to follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) when you name your classes, functions and variables

Comment: can you correct my coding and post it here, since i'm new to Framework and selenium, can you please post the correct code for me? from there i will learn

Comment: Please see if the edit helps.

Comment: This may be solution for my issue, but i created separate base class for all my reusable things, that was worked fine for me, But I'm really thankful for your answer, Thanks a lot